# registrar novos usuários usando o Ionic e o parse

Tags: javascript, ionic, parse.com

Eu to trabalhando em um app hibrido usando o ionic e o parse.

Quando eu vou no terminal e uso o comando `ionic serve`, e depois tento criar um novo usuario ou fazer o login, eu consigo sem problema nenhum, ou seja, no localhost está funcionando.

O problema é que, quando eu faço o build pro android e testo no celular, eu não consigo fazer o login e nem registrar novos usuários.

Alguém sabe me dizer o por que disso?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

A melhor coisa a se fazer é subir o ionic em modo debug e você acessar pelo celular, vai ser possível você ver os logs no console.

```
ionic run --consolelogs --serverlogs
```

Nas chamadas pro backend coloca alguns "alert" no sucesso e no erro, vai facilitar bastante.

Eu já tive alguns problemas com isso, porém estava utilizando outro framework, e era questões de permissões configuradas no meu backend.

Comment: Obrigado! vou tentar isso.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, vlw pela ajuda. No meu caso, eu estava chamando um script hospedado na parse.com. Só precisei baixar o script e adiciona-lo com os outros arquivos js.